# Смена консоли в Intellij IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, консоль

Как в Intellij IDEA сменить их встроенную консоль, на консоль ОС? Чтобы открывалась консоль именно windows.

Comment: так никак, это же именно эмулятор консоли

Answer (score 0):

Кнопка "Terminal" на нижней панели инструментов открывает системную консоль из корня проекта:

[image: terminal_button]

Если её там нет, можно вызвать через меню `View -> Tool Windows -> Terminal`

Comment: не является ответом на вопрос, т.к. автор хочет заменить эмулятор идеи на стандартный термин => он знает, как открыть эмулятор терминала идейки